# How do I get wordpress and Civicrm membership synced?

Tags: wordpress, civimember

I have tried multiple times to be able to get Wordpress and Civicrm to be able to sync up when members register. When I go to CiviMember Role Synchronize it redirects to the page for my blog.

What can I do to be able to get Civicrm members and Wordpress users to be able to register and login at the same time

Thank you for your help

Comment: Do you mean the CiviMember Sync extension settings? Also, does the profile on membership registration require account creation? User registration must be enabled on WP too.

Comment: Yes I mean the extension settings. No it doesn't and yes user registration is activated in Wordpress.

Comment: I have done this on the drupal version of this website.

Comment: I am not sure why that would be. Settings should be in wp-admin Settings > CiviMember Role Sync or yourdomain.org/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=civi_member_sync/list.php. Also to not the Profile used in Member registration should have Account creation required and the WP settings should allows Users to register.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for your help. Turns out I didn't do the first step to installing 
Wordpress Civicrm members sync:

> The first step is to Download the Plugin and put it under your sites
>   wp-content\plugins\ directory and rename the folder as
>   "civi_member_sync". Then Activate the plugin by going to your
>   WordPress site's Plugin page at
>   http://example.com/wp-admin/plugins.php It will be CiviMember Role
>   Synchronize.

https://github.com/jeevajoy/Wordpress-CiviCRM-Member-Role-Sync

Answer (score 3):

I know this post is old now. However, I struggled with a similar problem too, i wanted the user to become a Wordpress user at the same time they became a member, here are the steps I took to get it working in the end - hopefully this will help someone.

1. Wordpress > Setting > General > Membership > 'Anyone can register'
   must be checked.
2. Create a profile which includes the contacts primary email address
   this will be their email address in Wordpress too.
3. Add this profile to a contribution page (Contributions > New
   Contribution Page) on the 'Profiles' tab (above or below shouldn't
   matter - I add it at the top). The user should get prompted to enter
   their email address, username and password, and a Wordpress account
   will be created on successful submission. They're role will be whatever you have your default role in Wordpress set to.

Answer (score 2):

There is a CiviCRM function to synchronize Users to Contacts.  If you gave people WP logins, and their User records match up (primarily, email-wise) then you can run 'Synchronize Users to Contacts' under Users and Permissions.
 In Civi, Members are Contacts who are in a Group you defined - or are you using 'members' in a more general sense?  If these people are added to a Group you can find them under Search/Find Memberships

Comment: What I am trying to do is allow for people to register to be members under contribution pages but also get a login that they can use to edit their profile and for admins to be able to post via wordpress on it like. Members are defined as members.

Answer (score 1):

Where/how are they registering?

via Wordpress registration? CiviCRM form exposed by a widget in WP?

From my understanding, there is a sync function which existing in WP.. and you can specify the Wordpress table to use in the CiviCRM administration area. Any Wordpress logins will then create a CiviCRM contact. I don't know if the reverse sync is true i.e. CiviCRM to Wordpress as a user.

Check the CiviCRM config file points to the right database for CMS users (it should be the second connection string in the file).

Comment: They are registering via a contribution page in Civicrm. I will check that.